# C# AxAcroPDF.dll empty message box when launching program

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

I have been doing a program that should load a .pdf file and the use would be able to see the PDF within the pogram itself. However, using AxAcroPDFlib.dll, when I launch the program, sometimes it shows me an empty message box without loading the PDF, but sometimes it doesn't show the empty message box and loads the PDF correctly. I have included  the code I used to load the PDF. Unfortunately I dont have enough reputation to insert images, but I'll do my best do describe it.

It is a blank MessageBox type window, with the title "Adobe Reader" and a question mark on the left. There is also a small squared window (what the hell is this?) at it's left and it appears at the same time as the blank Messagebox.

Thank you for any help provided.

Here's the code:

```
 public List<String> G_Files = new List<String>();
 public int PDFCount = 0;
 public string G_LotID = string.Empty;
 public void LoadPDF(bool P_FirstTime)
    {
        string I_PDF = string.Empty;
        if (P_FirstTime)
        {
            PDFCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                I_PDF = G_Files[0].ToString();
                PDF_Reader.LoadFile(I_PDF);
                if (PDFCount > 0) { B_Previous.Enabled = true; }
                if (PDFCount < (G_Files.Count - 1)) { B_Next.Enabled = true; }
                else { B_Next.Enabled = false; }
                if (PDFCount > 0) { B_Previous.Enabled = true; }
                else { B_Previous.Enabled = false; }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            I_PDF = G_Files[PDFCount].ToString();
            PDF_Reader.LoadFile(I_PDF);
            if (PDFCount > 0) { B_Previous.Enabled = true; }
            else { B_Previous.Enabled = false; }
            if (PDFCount < (G_Files.Count - 1)) { B_Next.Enabled = true; }
            else { B_Next.Enabled = false; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Adobe Reader is a hopeless bag 'o bugs, very unwise to take a dependency on it.

Comment: Do you know any alternatives to Adobe Reader?

Comment: Michael, Try [pdfium.net sdk](http://pdfium.patagames.com) instead AxAcroPdf.

Comment: @MichaelAudren Have u fixed this error? I have the same error, 2.